# Get property call from parent class

Tags: php, selenium, magic-methods

I have the following code:

```
class Page extends APage{

    /**
     * @findby selector
     */
    protected $property

    public function getPropertyCount(){
        count($this->property);
    }

}


class APage{

    protected function initPropertyByAnnotation(){

    }      

}
```

Im using selenium with php, In selenium you select an element with a selector.
I want the parent class to detect a call to the childs property so i can handle the actual selecting.

I thought that this was possible through the __get magic method, but it turns out its only triggered when a property is not defined.

Is there a way to detect the call some way without using a helper method like getProperty?

Comment: __get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties. So if you don't define $property in the Page class, it will call __get

Comment: But i need to define it to set and read out the annotation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__get()` function changing the scope of your property to **private**.
As the docs says:

> __get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.

```
public function __get($field) {
    if ($field == 'property') { //the name of your property
        //do something that you want
    }
}
```